# 'comparison is always true due to limited range of data type' warning in C?

Tags: c, gcc, cell, warnings

I have the following code

```
//Point.h
#define WIDTH 8
#define HEIGHT 8

typedef struct Point
{
  char x;
  char y;
} Point;

//Board.c
#include <stdbool.h>

// Some other functions that we don't care about... 

bool inBounds(Point * p)
{
  return p->x >= 0
    && p->x <= WIDTH
    && p->y >= 0
    && p->y <= HEIGHT;
}
```

When I compile this (ppu-gcc 4.1.1), I get the following warning

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

even though the range of char is -127 to 127 and WIDTH is 8, which is well inside the range of a char. I've already tried an explicit cast of WIDTH to a char, but still got the error.

Comment: just change your struct to int, and see what happend?

Comment: In your case, you need to to atoi or static cast for x and y, then compare with height and width.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you sure that `char` is signed?  Try declaring the fields explictly as `signed char` and see what you get.

Comment: Yeah, I believe char is unsigned, so it's the comparison to 0 that will always be true.

Comment: It's compiler-dependent. If you *need* char to be signed, you need to declare it as signed.

Comment: Yeah this, fixes it. However, the lines that I was getting an error on were the lines where I was making a comparison against positive numbers (the WIDTH and HEIGHT). Strange.

Comment: The compiler must be using 0-based line numbers :-)  Actually, you may have a different problem there: Using <= and >= means that you have an effective WIDTH and HEIGHT range of 9, not 8. If that's what you want, perhaps you should use different macro names (MAX_X and MAX_Y?)

Answer (score 4):

I guess `x >= 0` causes the warning because `char` might be implemented as `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

The `char` type may be signed or unsigned. It depends on your compiler vendor's choice. There might even be a compiler option available. Evidently, `char` is unsigned for you, so it's always greater than or equal to zero, and thus the compiler warns you.

You're using `char` here to represent "a numeric type that takes up minimal memory." In that case, I recommend explicitly using `signed char` or `unsigned char`. (Each is distinct from plain `char`, despite `char` having to be either signed or unsigned.) Reserve `char` for when you're holding character data. For numeric data, use one of the other two types.

Comment: this is confirmed by: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_71.html

Answer (score 1):

Hummm... isn't your char unsigned by default? In that case the range would be 0-255, which means your >=0 comparison would be always true

Comment: It's platform- and compiler-dependent.  For example, GCC on x86 Linux uses signed char by default, while GCC on PowerPC Linux uses unsigned char by default.

Answer (score 1):

The C and C++ standards allows the character type char to be signed or unsigned, depending on the platform and compiler. Most systems, including x86 GNU/Linux and Microsoft Windows, use signed char, but those based on PowerPC and ARM processors typically use unsigned char.(29) This can lead to unexpected results when porting programs between platforms which have different defaults for the type of char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
typedef struct Point
{
  signed char x;
  signed char y;
} Point;
```